# TinyMCE in a div / textarea on frontend?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wp-enqueue-script

I have a post on my frontpage and I want to add the TinyMCE editor to it and could not make it work.

**I've tried these guides without any luck**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855890/add-tinymce-to-wordpress-plugin
- http://keighl.com/2010/01/tinymce-in-wordpress-plugins/

The guides are for making it work on backend.

**I guess I need to find out how to do these things...**

1. Add some Javascript with wp_enqueue_script.
2. Add some inline Javascript settings within script-tags.
3. Add a textarea or a div with a specific name, class or ID.

Help me in any way, code, links to guides, advice, anything.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is two things:

1. The [`wp_tiny_mce`](http://xref.yoast.com/trunk/nav.html?_functions/wp_tiny_mce.html) function that loads all the needed JS etc
2. The code below:

This to setup the JS etc:

```
// Setup the TinyMCE stuff and target it at our desired textarea
wp_tiny_mce( true, array( "editor_selector" => 'tinymce_class' ) );
```

And this HTML where you need the editor box:

```
<div class="editor_container">
    <textarea class="large-text tinymce_class" rows="5" id="tinymce_1" name="name">
        <?php echo esc_html($value) ?>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried something like that but it gives me: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_tiny_mce()" when calling it in the functions.php.

Maybe the code have changed in WP 3.2?

Comment: @Jens - Why are you be calling it in your functions file.. what are you hooking to, if anything? Everything you need is right there, so show us how you're implementing it(please).